# Confused about inserting a JS variable into Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'd like to scroll to a certain row in my HTML table, which contains dates in the format of

```
Nov-17-2021
```

Currently, I have this date.js function which gets today's date and inputs it in a `<span>`

```
const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
];

const d = new Date();

var today = new Date();

var date = today.getDate() + '-' + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + '-' + today.getFullYear();

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
```

I found that I can use JQuery to scroll easily to some text in a page with

```
function anotherFunction() {
    $(window).scrollTop($("table:contains('some text'):last").offset().top);
}
```

How can I use the variable `date` from my Javascript code to scroll to this text in my table, using JQuery? Essentially, I'd like a button that jumps to today's date in my table.

I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do this also, but I am an absolute beginner in programming and I don't know much, so I'm sorry for being very blunt and thank you!

Comment: Your date format doesn't match the provided text `Nov-17-2021` vs `17-Nov-2021` so they won't match unless you do a date parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using including the date in your string?

```
function anotherFunction() {
    date = document.getElementById("date").innerHTML
    $(window).scrollTop($(`table:contains(${date}):last`).offset().top);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the date string using string concatenation or string literals.

```
"table:contains(" + date +"):last"
`table:contains(${date}):last`
```

Example:

```js
// Fix a date for demo
var date = "18-Dec-2021"

$("button").click(() => {
  $(window).scrollTop($("tr:contains('" + date + "'):last").offset().top);
});
```

```css
td { height: 200px; border: 1px solid #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>01-Dec-2021</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10-Dec-2021</td></tr>
    <tr><td>18-Dec-2021</td></tr>
    <tr><td>31-Dec-2021</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `anotherFunction` is used to scroll to to an element inside a table having text `'some text'`.

Only what you have to do is, just trigger the function `anotherFunction` with some dynamic paramater for the text.

Below is how its done.

```js
function firstFunction() {
    const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    ];
    const d = new Date();
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getDate() + '-' + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + '-' + today.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
    anotherFunction(date)
}

function anotherFunction(text) {
    $(window).scrollTop($(`table:contains(${text}):last`).offset().top);
}
```

```css
table {
    margin-bottom: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Scroll to bottom and click the button</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="date">Your Date Will Appear here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="firstFunction()">Call First Function</button>
```